# Quartz Job Scheduler - Multi-Tenant Setup

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler, mariadb, multi-tenant

Since I haven't found anything related to that which would have lead me to inspiration, I thought I'd come up with this here.

I recently worked a lot with the [**Quartz Job Scheduler**](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) which I've already implemented within a RESTful Java Servlet that is supposed to offer a Sencha ExtJS-based UI for job creation. We use an Authenticator class in combination with a DatabaseManager that take care of authenticating users and all other database-specific stuff (using Hibernate).

Since we want to use it within the Java enterprise applications we develop, we need to run this thing for every customer. We also require the use of JobStoreTX for persistent data on MySQL databases (obviously for clustering), so volatile RAMJobStore implementation is a taboo. I am aware of the official documentation and that Quartz itself doesn't seem to support multi-tenant implementation (see [**Quartz Clustering**](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering)).

Our setup looks kinda like this (simplfied): 
- 1+ production Tomcat (serving application logic) 
- 1+ production Apache (serving ExtJS front-end and static content) 
- n databases (one for each customer)

To add something even more tricky: 
we have legacy modules that are customer-specific (each customer gets his own application hosting), while more up-to-date modules are hosted centralized with customer-related access.

In my opinion, it wouldn't be sufficient to created the Quartz-related tables on every customer database, since we want to stick with an easy, straight forward setup (which means e.g. same table prefix for each customer etc) just to not complicate the deployment of Quartz throughout the farm.

I already thought about combining it with **MariaDB MaxScale** and using **filters** to route Quartz to each customer database based on RegEx or something similar, with Quartz only talking to the MaxScale proxy, but this seemed a little bit too much overhead for what I try to achieve and I am not even sure if this would work at all.

Is there something that would give me **multi-tenancy with Quartz**? Could you suggest an approach that would make Quartz being able to handle this, since we need to run jobs for each customer, but on "one" Tomcat (which is actually clustered and loadbalanced)? Or is there another product/framework/library that supports multi-tenancy out of the box?

Any lead, idea or help is very much appreciated!

Comment: We are only in the development right now, but for now we chose to create the Quartz-related tables on every customer database. You can alter the quartz tables names through the quartz properties file if you want(so they will have the same table prefix for each customer etc).

Comment: I think I found a solution that can be applied easily to our software architecture. Since every customer has its own database, there is a system parameter that is available throughout the whole application logic, that is unique for each customer. This parameter will be attached to job and group names on creation automatically. This way we should be able to run Quartz on a single database for all customers.

Comment: Working smoothly so far. Just a question: From the interface I designed (using Sencha ExtJS) to create jobs, the user is given the choice to create one-time-only or recurring jobs. When I create a one-time-only job, the job (and trigger) don't persist in the database after execution. Is there a way to keep jobs that where already fired and that don't recur in the database?

Comment: I think it will always delete the job if there shouldn't be any more occurrences. If you want to save it for reuse of the user, then what we do is to save the scheduling data in a separate table. If you want logging, maybe [this](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigPlugins) will be useful for you.

Comment: Fixed it. There is a `@PersistJobDataAfterExecution` annotation for the Job class. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Anyway, I still have the requirement to make the solution work on multiple databases. My next approach will be creating the config file with customer's individual database configuration on-the-fly and see what happens. If anyone already tried this, please leave your feedback in this thread!

Answer (score 1):

you can use something called [JobDataMap](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html#jobdatamap) which is just map which you can use as your data container for each job.. What you have to do is:

- When creating new job, add some tenant identifier
- Create `globalJobListener` where you can inject tenant identifier from that map to you tenantContext

Here is my code:

```
// quartz configuration with custom job listener
@Configuration
public class MultiTenantQuartzAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory(jobFactory());
        schedulerFactoryBean.setGlobalJobListeners(new MultiTenantQuartzJobListener());

        return schedulerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory() {
        return new SpringBeanJobFactory();
    }
}

// custom job listener
public class MultiTenantQuartzJobListener implements JobListener {

    private static final String NAME = "tenantContext";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
        TenantContext.setTenantId(context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().getString(TenantContext.TENANT_HEADER));
    }

    @Override
    public void jobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext context) {
        TenantContext.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
        TenantContext.clear();
    }
}

// and here is how to create job with filled JobDataMap
Class c = Class.forName(jobInfo.getClassName());

JobDetail job = newJob(c)
        .withIdentity(jobInfo.getJobName(), jobInfo.getJobGroup())
        .withDescription(jobInfo.getDesc())
        .usingJobData(TenantContext.TENANT_HEADER, TenantContext.getTenantId())
        .build();

CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(jobInfo.getJobName(), jobInfo.getJobGroup())
        .withSchedule(cronSchedule(jobInfo.getCronExpression()))
        .build();

var ft = scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to write to multiple databases.

What I did was generating the Quartz properties file on-the-fly for each customer based on respective customer parameters and made the program logic read this newly generated file. So finally, each customer has its own Quartz jobs stored to its own database.

Comment: In this solution, you have one quartz scheduler for each customuer isn't it ? Because I never heard about quartz supporting multiple datasources. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Although it took some time to figure out how to dynamically create configurations for each tenant. Still, you'd need to figure out what on your side make a tenant "unique"..

Comment: Hello @MoshPit, It is really great that you have implemented. I would like to know that, how you have implemented it? Can you please explain in detail or provide some code example from your code. It will be really helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MoshPit Can you please share us information on how did you achieve this. I have a use case where we have multiple schemas in same db each schema should have its own schedulers