# Quartz Job Scheduler For a multi tenancy

Tags: quartz-scheduler, multi-tenant

I am planning to setup a Quartz scheduler which will only send out emails at scheduled time, i need multiple target Data source where quartz can perform jobs for multiple customers.

[Quartz Job Scheduler - Multi-Tenant Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847247/quartz-job-scheduler-multi-tenant-setup/28835513#28835513)

I followed this query,
But can some one point 
How did you generate quartz properties file on the fly and how did you make your program read those? can you help out giving more details with the implementation?

Comment: Did you manage to implement a multi-tenant scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

We have used the Quartz scheduler in our multi-tenant application, but we had the following variation

1. We create custom jobs that can look after the tenancy aspects
2. We try to utilize the Quartz for the scheduling part alone

Since there may be logic like setting the tenant context during some of the processing [like getting the tenant user email id], which can be a bit difficult to achieve out of the box with Quartz. However when you have the custom job written it will be easy for you to handle the business aspects easily.